# UnexpectedRollbackException keeps being thrown

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

There are couple of questions like that on the web, but no of the answers there could help :-( I keep getting the error. I tried:

1. @Transactional(readOnly = true, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
2. @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

In my setup I have several transactional services calling each other. In the last call down the hierarchy an exception is thrown and catched in the upper next. I placed the solution 1) on the upper most method where the transaction is created. I placed  2) on different levels in the middle. But nothing helped. What could be the issue? I thought that at least `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` could solve everything.